# jQuery UI draggable not working with jQueryUI 1.12.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

right now I am learning jQuery UI right now, but i am unable to drag the boxes i am creating with HTML and CSS. I am using HTML5 and CSS3 with jQuery version 1.12.1. Any help/suggestions would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

HTML code:

```
    <head>
        <title>jQueryUI Draggable</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

        <!--JqueryUI CSS-->
        <link href="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <h1>jQueryUI Draggable</h1>

            <div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div>
            <div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div>
            <div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div>
            <div id="box4" class="box">Box 4</div>
        </div>

        <!--If CDN Fails to load, serve up the local version-->
        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>

        <script src="jquery-ui-1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script src="script.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

The normalize CSS file is a simple file for edition HTML as a default:

```
.box{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    margin:0 20px;
}

#box1{
    background:lightblue;
}

#box2{
    background:lightgreen;
}

#box3{
    background:purple;
}

#box4{
    background:black;
}

.box:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

jQuery UI code:

```
$(function(){
    $('.box').draggable();
});
```

Comment: Just to add a comment I was able to select the text in the box as box1, box2, box3 and box4 but was not able to drag them.

Comment: Your code works, [check here](https://jsfiddle.net/Le5ghcxh/). Check your console for any errors it might be throwing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
 $('.box').draggable();
```

```css
.box{
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:white;
    margin:0 20px;
}

#box1{
    background:lightblue;
}

#box2{
    background:lightgreen;
}

#box3{
    background:purple;
}

#box4{
    background:black;
}

.box:hover{
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <div class="container">
            <h1>jQueryUI Draggable</h1>

            <div id="box1" class="box">Box 1</div>
            <div id="box2" class="box">Box 2</div>
            <div id="box3" class="box">Box 3</div>
            <div id="box4" class="box">Box 4</div>
</div>
```